# Feedback on font and color choices in the logo

Tags: logo, critique

I got my logo back from the designer, and I liked the logo image, but I didn't like the color choices or font. The font he used was too futuristic/space ship looking, and the colors were too heavy. I wanted to show a touch of playfulness and whimsy to highlight my personality.

So I have been playing around with the colors and fonts, but I am not sure it works.

Beacon Point, my business, offers one-on-one English tutoring, online writing courses, editing, and content writing.

**Option #1:**
I like the two purple colors (purple is my favorite color, and I thought the gold feather was playful and exciting, but it might be too much. I like the font in my business name, but it may not work with the font in my tagline.) [image: option 1]

**Option #2:**
This gets rid of the gold and simplifies the logo. But I am not sure if I like black being used in the loop. I also tried another font for business name, but I am still not sold. [image: Option 2]

Comment: The second one is better. Less is more and your logo should be legible in black and white (for faxes and scans) If you don't prefer the black make it purple or grey. I would consider using only a single font. perhaps the company name in a sans and the tagline in script. Your purple can be brighter and more vivid.

Comment: Don't use color, image And font to convey playfulness, just one of them.

Comment: @Webster, You said use a single font, but then said the company name in sans and the tagline in script.  Do you mean different variations of the same font? I thought sans fonts and script fonts were different fonts altogether, which would give me two fonts.

Thanks for your thoughtful and helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol with solid feather is great... shows movement, and some playfulness.

The textured feather is unrealistic where reproduction is concerned. That texture won't hold. It also drops focus from the feather and pushes focus to the circles making the symbol less dynamic overall.

I dislike the type in either choice. Pseudo script fonts, in my opinion, are "cheesy" in all most all uses other than wedding invitations. If you want a script font, use a script font. If you are concerned about readability, avoid scripts and pseudo scripts and choose a nice serif typeface. For logotypes, I generally prefer type be as *designed* as any symbology and not merely a chosen typeface.

It also *appears* as though the "writing your future" has been "stretched" or otherwise unnaturally extended horizontally, more so in the second image. I would not alter the default proportions of glyphs in a typeface if you are going to merely use a typeface.

All merely my opinion.... take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: what do you mean by you prefer type to be designed? Do you mean to not use a font already installed on my computer, but have someone design it? I wanted to use the same fonts found in my logo throughout my website, so I am not sure that would work. I just wanted to clarify that part of your comment.

Thank you for your feedback. It was helpful.

Comment: RE same font as logo for web site -- see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42000/should-my-websites-typography-use-the-same-font-as-my-logo I, personally would *never* try and match a logo's typeface to the rest of the layout.

Comment: What I mean by "design the type" is... a **logo** should rarely be as simple as picking a typeface from a list in an application.  Any 7 year old can do that. That's *not* design. That's picking a font. How glyphs in the type interact with one another or the symbology can be explored and often a more solid overall *logo* is achieved. Just my methodology, I'm not stating it's the only method though.

Comment: I cannot design my own font since I am not a designer. So I am left to picking a typeface from a list. I have played around with different font combos. I was hoping you would tell me which one or two work well. I'll be honest: I tend to gravitate to the "cheesy" "cutsey" and think regular sans and sans-serif fonts are "boring," so I prefer option 3,4, or 5. But if 1 or 2 are better for professionalism, then I will go with that.



https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bnoho2jfj37rfei/AADZzC9G-FZ5F-0fZQZNNWbqa?dl=0